# Symfony2 my Controller: requires that you provide a value for the "$idn"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I've a function that set a column name after clicking on the button

```
public function luAction($idn)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rech = $em->getRepository('NewsBundle:News_PNC')->findOneBy($idn);
    if (!$rech) {
        return new Response('Error');
    }
    else {
        $rech->setLu('lu');
        $em->persist($rech);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('pnc');
    }
}
```

you can see also my routing.yml

```
     lu_news:
         path:  /lu/{idn}
         defaults: {_controller: NewsBundle:news:lu}
```

The function that return the id from the database:

```
public function pncAction()
{       
    $user= $this->getUser();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('NewsBundle:News_PNC');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->where('p.pncs = :user')
                        ->addSelect('p.lu')
                        ->addSelect('p.idn')
                       ->andWhere('p.lu = :no')
                        ->leftJoin('p.news','news')
                        ->addSelect('news.id')
                        ->setParameter('user',$user->getId())
                       ->setParameter('no','no')
                        ->getQuery();

    $users = $query->getResult();
    $tab = array();

    $tab1 = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        array_push($tab, $user); //retourne l id du news
        array_push ($tab1,$user['id']); // retourne l id du l'utilisateur connecté
    }

   /* dump($tab);
    exit() ; */

   $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('NewsBundle:news');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->where('p.id = :id')
                        ->setParameter('id',$tab1[0])
                        ->getQuery();

    $news = $query->getResult();
       return $this->render('popup.html.twig',
        array('user' => $users , 'news'=>$news));
}
}
```

My Twig:

```
<a href="{{path('lu_news',{'idn':l.idn})}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Continuer</a>
```

when i clic on the button i see this in my URL which means it brings me the right ID :

```
    http://127.0.0.1/sym/web/app_dev.php/lu/2
```

and after getting this URL  it show me this error

**Controller "NewsBundle\Controller\newsController::luAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$idn" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).**

Comment: just tested this in my enviroment an it works without issues, could you post your full `routing.yml`? also, which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: Symfony2.8 , i guess it's not about my full routing ! no ? actually the i.iden 
from my QueryBuilder

Comment: I mean the full (or more relevant tree) `routing.yml` file, paste it inside your answer ;)

Comment: i don't understand what's the full routing.yml you want , you want all my routes ? anyway i put the route of the Function my routing.yml inside my bundle not in app/config/routing.yml

Comment: Anyway problem resolved by clearing the cache

Comment: lol... so no issues! forgot to ask for the cache actually :P

Comment: lol u make me laugh -_- !